# Traffic being lost with header location redirect PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website which redirects a large amount of traffic to other websites using:

`header("Location: http://example.com/")`

Essentially, the process is as follows:

1. User enters my website and passes some security checks, their visit is logged and they're redirected to another page. (They do not login, their ip is checked, referrer, etc)
2. The users log entry is verified (entry was created in step 1) and they are redirected to an external URL.
3. User is now on the external URL web page.

Between Step 1 being initialized and Step 3 being completed, everything is automatic. It usually takes 1-2 seconds for the entire process to complete and the user to end up on the final external website.

The issue I'm having is that roughly 35% of the traffic disappears between steps 2 and 3. I created a debug log entry directly before the `header("Location:...` in step 2, and another at the very top of the file in step 3 and the discrepancy is there.

To give you a general idea, there is roughly 4000 users per minute at step 2, while there is only roughly 2500 users per minute at step 3.

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this to happen, and I'm hoping someone may be able to provide some insight.

For debugging I am simply inserting an entry into the database at both Step 2 before sending the visitor out, and at Step 3 as soon as the external website is loaded. The code used for this is:

Step 2 end:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO log SET step = '2', time = '".time()."'";
$result = $db->query( $query );

header( "Location: " . $chosen['url'] );
die();
```

Step 3 start after database class loaded:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO log SET step = '3', time = '".time()."'";
$result = $db->query( $query );
```

Note that there is no code whatsoever between the logging in Step 2 and the redirect. It is essentially impossible for the `header("Location...` to not be reached.

Comment: This is not uncommon. Many users fail to finish a workflow for various reasons.

Comment: @JohnConde can you provide any insight into what these reasons may be?

Comment: I agree with John Conde. It seems strange to log in to one site to be re-directed to another. What is the context?

Comment: @Parapluie Sorry for the confusion, the user does not login. The security checks are all automatic (IP, Referrer, etc) and then they are automatically redirected. It all happens seamlessly on the users end and should be instant (less than 1 second between step 1 initialized and step 3 complete).

Comment: @BelginFish how are you measuring the traffic at step 3?  If you're using a 3rd party tracking utility, it's possible that you're logging 1500 spider/bot visits in step 1 that aren't getting recorded by your analytics tool.  It's also possible you have a bug in Site #2 that's causing it to fail for 1/3 of your traffic.

Comment: @StevenMoseley for the purpose of debugging the issue, I have done all the tracking myself using a simple database insert query for both step 2 and step 3 logging. I then compared the number of entries to come up with my 35% figure.

Comment: @Veve I have updated the initial question to contain the basics of my logging and redirect.

Comment: Did you make sure the issue did not come from the script of step 2? A error or a notice might prevent the execution of the redirection thus leaving a blank screen. Set `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see if there is anything wrong in step 2.

Comment: Are you using a client side analyzer (eg.: google analytics) to cross and match the number of requests?

Comment: @Youmy001 PHP is set to show no errors whatsoever, so there should be nothing blocking the redirect.

Comment: @GabrielHeming I am using my own database logging to match the number of requests. See the code at the bottom of the question.

Comment: That's not I'm saying. I'm asking if you can cross your database log with a client side log (step 3, of course).

Comment: @GabrielHeming unfortunately a client side log such as google analytics is returning the same amount of traffic as the custom logger I have implemented.  This is what got me looking into the issue initially, google analytics returning a different number on the external websites than I was logging as being sent out from step 2.